# BatchNormalization Bijector Wrong Result with "prob" method

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to implement a normalizing flow according to the RealNVP model for density estimation.
First, I am trying to make it work on the ["moons" toy dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_moons.html).

The model produces the expected result when **not** using the BatchNormalization bijector. However, when adding the BatchNormalization bijector to the model, the methods `prob` and `log_prob` return unexpected results.

Following is a code snippet setting up the model:

```py
layers = 6
dimensions = 2
hidden_units = [512, 512]
bijectors = []

base_dist = tfd.Normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0)  # specify base distribution

for i in range(layers):
    # Adding the BatchNormalization bijector corrupts the results
    bijectors.append(tfb.BatchNormalization())
    bijectors.append(RealNVP(input_shape=dimensions, n_hidden=hidden_units))
    bijectors.append(tfp.bijectors.Permute([1, 0]))

bijector = tfb.Chain(bijectors=list(reversed(bijectors))[:-1], name='chain_of_real_nvp')

flow = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
    distribution=tfd.Sample(base_dist, sample_shape=[dimensions]),
    bijector=bijector
)
```

When to BatchNormalization bijector is ommited both sampling and evaluating the probability return expected results:

[image: Without BN: Heatmap constructed with]

However, when the BatchNormalization bijector is added, sampling is as expected but evaluating the probability seems wrong:

[image: With BN: Heatmap constructed with]

Because I am interested in density estimation the `prob` method is crucial. The full code can be found in the following jupyter notebook:
https://github.com/mmsbrggr/normalizing-flows/blob/master/moons_training_rnvp.ipynb

I know that the BatchNormalization bijector behaves differently during training and inference. Could the problem be that the BN bijector is still in training mode? If so how can I move the flow to inference mode?

Comment: You can use the `training=False` argument to the `BatchNormalization`.  You'll need to rebuild your model in that case.